# if search query is met function

Tags: wordpress, search, if-statement, web

I want to create a function for wordpress that display a particular banner only if certain search terms stored in array are entered into the search box.

So for example if i entered the string "yellow" I would get a banner and search results for that string because it is in the array

But if i entered the string "orange" I would only get search terms

not too sure where to start with this so any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

Daniel Wakefield
[Web Designer Cheshire](http://www.dubcode.co.uk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a word exists within a search term, add each searched word into an array using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Then use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to see if that word exists.

```
$words_array = explode(' ', $_GET['s']);
if(in_array('orange', $words_array)) {
    // search contains orange
} else { 
    // search does not contain orange
}
```

Comment: Tried it out but no joy unfortunately, 
im putting this on the search results page

Comment: Im Using the code below but just getting the else echo

   
        $words_array = explode('hello, orange, goodbye', get_query_var('s'));
        if(in_array('hello', $words_array)) {
        echo "<h5>OBJECT IN ARRAY</h5>";
         } else {
        echo "<h5>OBJECT NOT IN ARRAY</h5>";
        }

Comment: Form Code

<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<input type="text" size="12" name="s" id="s" value="search" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
<input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit" /> 
</form>

Comment: The form is fine. I've just made a quick edit. It's untested but you might have to customise it slightly to avoid duplicate keyword matching.

Comment: Im definatelly getting the logic behind this one but im getting a syntax error "unexpected {" heres my code

$words_to_match = array('orange', 'green', 'blue');
$search_array = explode(' ', get_query_var('s'));
foreach($words_to_match as $object) {
  if(in_array($object, $search_array) {
    echo 'true';
  } else {
    echo 'false';
  }
}

Comment: Sorry I missed a bracket, hasty writing ;) .. get_query_var('s')) Changed it try now.

Comment: Im getting no more syntax error now, but the only result im getting is "falsefalsefalse" whether i input something from the array or not

Hhhhmm

Comment: I've just tested this and it worked fine for me. Once you perform a search and the results are rendered, can you confirm what your URL string looks like in the address bar?

Comment: www.domain.com/?s=orange

Comment: I'm sorry but this has worked as expected for me by returning the results truefalsefalse. I don't think I can be of any further help.

Comment: I think i may have mis-explained as this code below seems to be what i want but i keep getting a syntax error, I want it so if someone types in "orange" a banner shows if they dont it shows something else

Does that make sense?


$words_array = explode(' ', get_query_var('s'));
if(in_array('orange', $words_array)) {
  // true
} else {
  //false 
}

Comment: There are no syntax errors in that code. I would think the syntax error is coming from somewhere else in your code. 
I've just tested it and it works as expected. If the word 'orange' appears in the search term that will return true. If not then false. Obviously where it is true add your banner code there, then your fallback where it returns false.

Just a quick one - you are separating the comment lines from the end of condition brackets right?

Comment: The syntax error was at my end, sorry to bug you, i do appreciate your help. Here is my full code, still all i get is false
<?php
$words_array = explode(' ', get_query_var('s'));
if(in_array('orange', $words_array)) {
echo "<h5>true</h5>";
} else {
echo "<h5>false</h5>";
}
 ?>

Comment: I honestly don't know what to say that can further help you, sorry. When the URL string is /?s=orange that code returns true for me.

Comment: Last try - try substituting get_query_var('s') with $_GET['s']

Comment: So here is the working function, thanks for all the help JB

    <?php
    $words_array = explode(' ', $_GET['s']);
    if(in_array('orange', $words_array)) {
    echo "<h5>true</h5>";
    } else {
    echo "<h5>false</h5>";
    }
    ?>

Comment: Thanks buddy. I've updated the final answer. If you're happy with it would you be so kind as to tick this off?

Comment: Hey joe, (that's the name of my fave jimi song:) I have noticed a problem now I have started to add multiple queries I only seem to get the latest baner from the cat and not the specified ID hope that makes sense can post code if it helps D

Comment: OK I fixed it ,(my error, not joe buckle) i was using post_id= but found using p= did the job cheers Joe

http://pastebin.com/ZtxXdSNW

Comment: No probs took me a while to work out how to mark as answered
cheers for all your help